# Alpha testers upgraded to prod, subscribed, what happens if I push a new build?

Tags: android, google-play

So I have a situation where my alpha users were upgraded to the production version automatically. (I found this quite alarming as AppStore is segregated from TestFlight.)

Some of those users have subscribed to my app which is subscription only.

I see now that Play Store users are automatically pushed to the track  with the highest build number that is available to them.

So my question is this: what happens if I push a new build number to Alpha? Will the subscribed users continue to be charged? If they cancel their subscription in Alpha, will it cancel their subscription in Prod?

I have some users who want to continue testing, and others who want to continue as paying customers. How do I handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Play, users will always get upgraded to the highest version code that is available to them. And the production version is available to all users. If the Production track version code is higher than the Alpha, then as you have found, users will get the production version. If the Alpha version code is then increased to be higher than the production version they will get upgraded to the Alpha.

If your users want to go to the production version, just get them to opt-out of the Alpha. They can do this by going to the original opt-in link and opting out.

Comment: Thank you, that answer the question about how they opt out. My most important question is what happens to their production subscription if I publish an alpha with a higher build number?

Comment: That depends how you have implemented subscriptions in your code. On the Play side there is no difference on a subscription from Alpha  or Prod, so no such thing as an Alpha or production subscription. A subscription is just a subscription in the billing code.